# Dojo Web Builder: Packages Missing

Tags: javascript, eclipse, dojo, maven-jetty-plugin

I've been able to build and run the [Dojo Web Builder](https://github.com/dojo/dwb) fine with Jetty on my localhost, but the following error pops up in the console, leading to no packages/modules to be found in the module explorer window:

[Picture of console error and DWB interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOqsN.png)

I've tried several different versions of Dojo.js (1.13, 1.8.0, 1.7.2, 1.6) and changing the dojo.source argument to feed to Jetty several different ways, to no avail.

Has anyone had this issue or located what config files might need to be changed?  I stepped through the instructions on their GitHub but I couldn't find anything that I misconfigured or did not set up in the first place besides supporting custom modules.

Edit:

The problematic code is in the condensed dwb.js file on line 6 ("name": pkge.name):

```
_packageModulesAvailable: function(_c54) {
        var _c55 = [];
        this.baseProfile.packages = [];
        dojo.forEach(_c54, dojo.hitch(this, function(pkge) {
            this.baseProfile.packages.push({
                "name": pkge.name,
                "version": pkge.version
            });
            dojo.forEach(pkge.modules, dojo.hitch(this, function(_c56) {
                var item = this._generateModuleGridItem(pkge.name, _c56);
                _c55.push(item);
            }));
        }));
        this.store = new dojox.data.AndOrWriteStore({
            data: {
                "identifier": "name",
                "items": _c55
            }
        });
        this.module_grid.setStore(this.store);
        this.analysePane.set("globalModulesStore", this.store);
        this.updateModuleFilter();
},
```